# Select for JSON is not rounded as per query

Tags: json, sql-server

A simple SQL query in Microsoft SQL Server:

> SELECT ROUND(SUM(amount), 2) AS 'Amount' 
>   FROM accvoucherlines 
>   WHERE vid=10000174

returns results properly rounded like `712.72`

But same query, when suffixed by `'FOR JSON PATH'` returns numbers in scientific format like `[{"Amount":7.127200000000000e+002}]`

I actually need rounded values in JSON format. Why is it not working as expected?

Comment: `7.1272x10^2 = 712.72`. That **is** the rounded value (represented as a floating point value). What value are you expected if not `712.72`?

Comment: SQL Server formats this weirdly because it arbitrarily chooses to stick floating types in this format, whereas it won't do that for decimal types (compare `SELECT v = 712.72e FOR JSON PATH`, `SELECT v = 712.72 FOR JSON PATH`). JSON only has floating point for numbers, so this is not completely unreasonable. The value is correct and should be processed correctly by clients; if you really want a different string representation (which does *not* change the underlying value and should have no *actual* effect) cast the result to an appropriate `DECIMAL(x, 2)` type.

Comment: @Larnu I am expecting `712.72` and not `7.127200000000000e+002` of the same number. It's that easy.

Comment: Then you need to `CONVERT` to a `decimal` as @JeroenMostert mentioned. YOur value is a `float`, and so that's the value that's put in your JSON too.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert. Please post your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Push SQL to reduce decimal places by converting number to DECIMAL(18,2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),ROUND(SUM(a.amount), 2)) AS [Amount]
FROM accvoucherlines a
WHERE a.vid=10000174
FOR JSON PATH
;
```

Query to play around:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),ROUND(SUM(a.amount),2)) AS [Amount]
FROM (VALUES(3.45634563),(5.1273322)) a(amount)
FOR JSON PATH
;
```